# How to take only the field which have Maximum fields

Tags: python, xml, logging, count, python-logging

```
logger.info("Audit Report capture process start")
for clientid in clients:

    files = xmlgenops.loadFileslist(clientid, os.path.join(filepath, clientid , 'Outgoing'), 'xml')

    totalFiles[clientid] = len(files)
    total_files += len(files)
    logger.info ("Processing for client '{}'".format(clientid))
    files_with_issues = 0
    file_header_print = True

    for filename in files:
        filename = filename[1]
        fullfilename = os.path.join(filepath, clientid , "Outgoing", filename)
        clientcount[clientid] = clientcount[clientid] + 1 if  clientcount.get(clientid) else 1
        headstr = "Client:SeqNo:Filename"
        datastr = "{}:{}:{}".format(clientid, clientcount[clientid], filename)
        try:
            xmltree = ET.parse(fullfilename)
        except ET.ParseError as err:
            print("xml parse error")
            clienterror[clientid] = clienterror[clientid] + 1 if  clienterror.get(clientid) else 1
            fileswitherror.append("{}:{}".format(datastr, err))
            continue

        myroot = xmltree.getroot()

        for i in myroot.iter('record'):
            file_header_print = True
            for j in i.iter(): 
                if j.tag == 'row':
                    # If we encounter a row element, iterate over its children instead
                    for k in j.iter():
                        if k.tag not in ignoretags:
                            if file_header_print:
                                headstr = "{}:{}".format(headstr, k.tag)
                            datastr = "{}:{}".format(datastr, k.text)
                else:
                    if j.tag not in ignoretags:
                        if file_header_print:
                            headstr = "{}:{}".format(headstr, j.tag)
                        datastr = "{}:{}".format(datastr, j.text)

            if file_header_print:
                file_header_print = False
                logger.info(headstr)
            logger.info(datastr)

logger.info("Audit Report capture process end")
```

The above code is the part of my code which gives me a log report given below

```
2023-03-13 10:13:29,957 : INFO : audreport : Audit Report : START
2023-03-13 10:13:29,973 : INFO : audreport : Database connection established
2023-03-13 10:13:29,978 : INFO : audreport : Processing for clients '['AD', 'AW', 'CC']' User: Lukmana
2023-03-13 10:13:30,116 : INFO : audreport : Loading files from 'Y:/PMT_Training/Softco_Files
2023-03-13 10:13:30,116 : INFO : audreport : Audit Report capture process start
2023-03-13 10:13:30,119 : INFO : audreport : Processing for client 'AD'
2023-03-13 10:13:30,134 : INFO : audreport : Client:SeqNo:Filename:organization:case_id:invoice_number:supplier_number:supplier_name:posting_date:currency_code:gross_amount:tax_amount:net_amount:order_number:invoice_source:invoice_capture_date:document_type:data_capture_provider_code:data_capture_provider_reference:document_capture_provide_code:document_capture_provider_ref:data_capture_issue:from_email:to_email:box_number:data_captured:data_container:pdf_file_name:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount
2023-03-13 10:13:30,134 : INFO : audreport : AD:1:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296919.xml:1020:2296919:1007173604:0000155186:HIGH PURITY PRODUCTS INC:2022-10-28:USD:21325.00:0.00:21325.00:45907133:Email:2022-11-01:INVOICE:00001:588528:00002:588528:None:angela.espinosa@highpp.com:None:None:None:None:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296919.pdf:1:45907133:65-6554:None:None:316.0000:EA:27.00:8532.00:1:45907133:65-6554:None:None:316.0000:EA:27.00:8532.00:2:45907133:65-6610:None:None:482.0000:EA:2.00:964.00:2:45907133:65-6610:None:None:482.0000:EA:2.00:964.00:3:45907133:65-6513:None:None:68.0000:EA:1.00:68.00:3:45907133:65-6513:None:None:68.0000:EA:1.00:68.00:4:45907133:65-6507:None:None:64.0000:EA:8.00:512.00:4:45907133:65-6507:None:None:64.0000:EA:8.00:512.00:5:45907133:65-6506:None:None:73.0000:EA:4.00:292.00:5:45907133:65-6506:None:None:73.0000:EA:4.00:292.00:6:45907133:65-6509M:None:None:64.0000:EA:27.00:1728.00:6:45907133:65-6509M:None:None:64.0000:EA:27.00:1728.00:7:45907133:65-6611:None:None:472.0000:EA:4.00:1888.00:7:45907133:65-6611:None:None:472.0000:EA:4.00:1888.00:8:45907133:65-6510:None:None:134.0000:EA:3.00:402.00:8:45907133:65-6510:None:None:134.0000:EA:3.00:402.00:9:45907133:65-6502:None:None:184.0000:EA:2.00:368.00:9:45907133:65-6502:None:None:184.0000:EA:2.00:368.00:10:45907133:65-6607:None:None:266.0000:EA:6.00:1596.00:10:45907133:65-6607:None:None:266.0000:EA:6.00:1596.00:11:45907133:65-6508:None:None:78.0000:EA:27.00:2106.00:11:45907133:65-6508:None:None:78.0000:EA:27.00:2106.00:12:45907133:65-6508T:None:None:2734.0000:EA:1.00:2734.00:12:45907133:65-6508T:None:None:2734.0000:EA:1.00:2734.00:13:45907133:FREIGHT CHARGES:None:None:135.0000:EA:1.00:135.00:13:45907133:FREIGHT CHARGES:None:None:135.0000:EA:1.00:135.00
2023-03-13 10:13:30,167 : INFO : audreport : Client:SeqNo:Filename:organization:case_id:invoice_number:supplier_number:supplier_name:posting_date:currency_code:gross_amount:tax_amount:net_amount:order_number:invoice_source:invoice_capture_date:document_type:data_capture_provider_code:data_capture_provider_reference:document_capture_provide_code:document_capture_provider_ref:data_capture_issue:from_email:to_email:box_number:data_captured:data_container:pdf_file_name:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount
2023-03-13 10:13:30,167 : INFO : audreport : AD:3:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296925.xml:1020:2296925:71074269:0000155186:STAUFFER GLOVE SAFETY:2022-10-27:USD:2584.72:12.90:2571.82:47007526:Email:2022-11-01:INVOICE:00001:588534:00002:588534:None:Robin.Nogues@analog.com:None:None:None:None:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296925.pdf:1:47007526:N014187:None:None:157.70:EA:15:2365.50:1:47007526:N014187:None:None:157.70:EA:15:2365.50:2:47007526:N014258:None:None:51.58:EA:4:206.32:2:47007526:N014258:None:None:51.58:EA:4:206.32
2023-03-13 10:13:30,188 : INFO : audreport : Client:SeqNo:Filename:organization:case_id:invoice_number:supplier_number:supplier_name:posting_date:currency_code:gross_amount:tax_amount:net_amount:order_number:invoice_source:invoice_capture_date:document_type:data_capture_provider_code:data_capture_provider_reference:document_capture_provide_code:document_capture_provider_ref:data_capture_issue:from_email:to_email:box_number:data_captured:data_container:pdf_file_name:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount
2023-03-13 10:13:30,188 : INFO : audreport : AD:4:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296961.xml:1010:2296961:0000007624:0000137879:CDW DIRECT LLC:2022-11-01:USD:460.42:35.68:424.74:45922117:Email:2022-11-01:INVOICE:00001:588549:00002:588549:None:cdwbilling@billtrust.com:None:None:None:None:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296961.pdf:1:45922117:997-7413-01:None:None:409.59:EA:1:409.59:1:45922117:997-7413-01:None:None:409.59:EA:1:409.59:2:45922117:SHIPPING:None:None:15.15:EA:1:15.15:2:45922117:SHIPPING:None:None:15.15:EA:1:15.15
2023-03-13 10:13:30,429 : INFO : audreport : Processing for client 'AW'
2023-03-13 10:13:30,429 : INFO : audreport : Client:SeqNo:Filename:organization:case_id:invoice_number:supplier_number:supplier_name:posting_date:currency_code:gross_amount:tax_amount:net_amount:order_number:invoice_source:invoice_capture_date:document_type:data_capture_provider_code:data_capture_provider_reference:document_capture_provide_code:document_capture_provider_ref:data_capture_issue:from_email:to_email:box_number:data_captured:data_container:pdf_file_name:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount
2023-03-13 10:13:30,429 : INFO : audreport : AW:1:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296984.xml:1010:2296984:7722074583:0000132929:VANGUARD INTL SEMICONDUCTOR CORP:2022-11-01:USD:21850.00:0.00:21850.00:45971694:Email:2022-11-01:INVOICE:00001:588572:00002:588572:None:VIS_OM@VIS.COM.TW:None:None:None:None:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296984.pdf:1:45971694:8VL3850PXV-B0VG:None:None:874.00:EA:25:21850.00:1:45971694:8VL3850PXV-B0VG:None:None:874.00:EA:25:21850.00
2023-03-13 10:13:30,444 : INFO : audreport : Client:SeqNo:Filename:organization:case_id:invoice_number:supplier_number:supplier_name:posting_date:currency_code:gross_amount:tax_amount:net_amount:order_number:invoice_source:invoice_capture_date:document_type:data_capture_provider_code:data_capture_provider_reference:document_capture_provide_code:document_capture_provider_ref:data_capture_issue:from_email:to_email:box_number:data_captured:data_container:pdf_file_name:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount
2023-03-13 10:13:30,444 : INFO : audreport : AW:2:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296985.xml:1010:2296985:7722074586:0000132929:VANGUARD INTL SEMICONDUCTOR CORP:2022-11-01:USD:22575.00:0.00:22575.00:45968296:Email:2022-11-01:INVOICE:00001:588573:00002:588573:None:VIS_OM@VIS.COM.TW:None:None:None:None:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296985.pdf:1:45968296:8VL8609-1XV-B1VG:None:None:903.00:EA:25:22575.00:1:45968296:8VL8609-1XV-B1VG:None:None:903.00:EA:25:22575.00
2023-03-13 10:13:30,460 : INFO : audreport : Client:SeqNo:Filename:organization:case_id:invoice_number:supplier_number:supplier_name:posting_date:currency_code:gross_amount:tax_amount:net_amount:order_number:invoice_source:invoice_capture_date:document_type:data_capture_provider_code:data_capture_provider_reference:document_capture_provide_code:document_capture_provider_ref:data_capture_issue:from_email:to_email:box_number:data_captured:data_container:pdf_file_name:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount
2023-03-13 10:13:30,622 : INFO : audreport : Processing for client 'CC'
2023-03-13 10:13:30,637 : INFO : audreport : Client:SeqNo:Filename:organization:case_id:invoice_number:supplier_number:supplier_name:posting_date:currency_code:gross_amount:tax_amount:net_amount:order_number:invoice_source:invoice_capture_date:document_type:data_capture_provider_code:data_capture_provider_reference:document_capture_provide_code:document_capture_provider_ref:data_capture_issue:from_email:to_email:box_number:data_captured:data_container:pdf_file_name
2023-03-13 10:13:30,637 : INFO : audreport : CC:1:11a77bd9-ede6-4e53-942e-b9fa103d5736_1361879.xml:00040:1361879:68481161:30150461:CARGILL NV (BEL):2022-11-19:EUR:13350.40:0.00:13350.40:5188633:Email:2022-11-21:INVOICE:None:None:001:1524:None:CargillCSSTEU_Invoice_DoNotReply@cargill.com:None:None:None:None:11a77bd9-ede6-4e53-942e-b9fa103d5736_1361879.pdf
2023-03-13 10:13:30,653 : INFO : audreport : Client:SeqNo:Filename:organization:case_id:invoice_number:supplier_number:supplier_name:posting_date:currency_code:gross_amount:tax_amount:net_amount:order_number:invoice_source:invoice_capture_date:document_type:data_capture_provider_code:data_capture_provider_reference:document_capture_provide_code:document_capture_provider_ref:data_capture_issue:from_email:to_email:box_number:data_captured:data_container:pdf_file_name
2023-03-13 10:13:30,653 : INFO : audreport : CC:2:11a77bd9-ede6-4e53-942e-b9fa103d5736_1361880.xml:00030:1361880:9160543447:30130087:DIAGEO NI:2022-11-17:GBP:32426.76:5404.46:27022.30:89095:Email:2022-11-21:INVOICE:None:None:001:1519:None:ops_batch.dep@diageo.com:None:None:None:None:11a77bd9-ede6-4e53-942e-b9fa103d5736_1361880.pdf
2023-03-13 10:13:30,678 : INFO : audreport : Client:SeqNo:Filename:organization:case_id:invoice_number:supplier_number:supplier_name:posting_date:currency_code:gross_amount:tax_amount:net_amount:order_number:invoice_source:invoice_capture_date:document_type:data_capture_provider_code:data_capture_provider_reference:document_capture_provide_code:document_capture_provider_ref:data_capture_issue:from_email:to_email:box_number:data_captured:data_container:pdf_file_name
2023-03-13 10:13:30,678 : INFO : audreport : CC:3:2b21abc3-2c56-46df-8e86-f6af8b17560e_1361468.xml:00040:1361468:413502322:30110395:KERRY INGREDIENTS & FLAVOURS LTD:2022-11-18:EUR:20250.00:0.00:20250.00:5191015:Email:2022-11-21:INVOICE:None:None:001:1512:Incorrect PO:noreply.kerryconnect@kerry.com:None:None:None:None:2b21abc3-2c56-46df-8e86-f6af8b17560e_1361468.pdf
2023-03-13 10:13:30,705 : INFO : audreport : Client:SeqNo:Filename:organization:case_id:invoice_number:supplier_number:supplier_name:posting_date:currency_code:gross_amount:tax_amount:net_amount:order_number:invoice_source:invoice_capture_date:document_type:data_capture_provider_code:data_capture_provider_reference:document_capture_provide_code:document_capture_provider_ref:data_capture_issue:from_email:to_email:box_number:data_captured:data_container:pdf_file_name
```

you can see AD, AW, CC these are each client. my question is simple, the current log report have headers for each file in each client. i only wanted a single header on top of each client but the header must be the one with the maximum length or the longest one from each client.My expected result is:

```
Audit Report : START
2023-03-13 10:11:25,722 : INFO : audreport : Database connection established
2023-03-13 10:11:25,738 : INFO : audreport : Processing for clients '['AD', 'AW', 'CC']' User: Lukmana
2023-03-13 10:11:25,864 : INFO : audreport : Loading files from 'Y:/PMT_Training/Softco_Files
2023-03-13 10:11:25,864 : INFO : audreport : Audit Report capture process start
2023-03-13 10:11:25,864 : INFO : audreport : Processing for client 'AD'
2023-03-13 10:11:25,879 : INFO : audreport : Client:SeqNo:Filename:organization:case_id:invoice_number:supplier_number:supplier_name:posting_date:currency_code:gross_amount:tax_amount:net_amount:order_number:invoice_source:invoice_capture_date:document_type:data_capture_provider_code:data_capture_provider_reference:document_capture_provide_code:document_capture_provider_ref:data_capture_issue:from_email:to_email:box_number:data_captured:data_container:pdf_file_name:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount
2023-03-13 10:11:25,879 : INFO : audreport : AD:1:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296919.xml:1020:2296919:1007173604:0000155186:HIGH PURITY PRODUCTS INC:2022-10-28:USD:21325.00:0.00:21325.00:45907133:Email:2022-11-01:INVOICE:00001:588528:00002:588528:None:angela.espinosa@highpp.com:None:None:None:None:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296919.pdf:1:45907133:65-6554:None:None:316.0000:EA:27.00:8532.00:2:45907133:65-6610:None:None:482.0000:EA:2.00:964.00:3:45907133:65-6513:None:None:68.0000:EA:1.00:68.00:4:45907133:65-6507:None:None:64.0000:EA:8.00:512.00:5:45907133:65-6506:None:None:73.0000:EA:4.00:292.00:6:45907133:65-6509M:None:None:64.0000:EA:27.00:1728.00:7:45907133:65-6611:None:None:472.0000:EA:4.00:1888.00:8:45907133:65-6510:None:None:134.0000:EA:3.00:402.00:9:45907133:65-6502:None:None:184.0000:EA:2.00:368.00:10:45907133:65-6607:None:None:266.0000:EA:6.00:1596.00:11:45907133:65-6508:None:None:78.0000:EA:27.00:2106.00:12:45907133:65-6508T:None:None:2734.0000:EA:1.00:2734.00:13:45907133:FREIGHT CHARGES:None:None:135.0000:EA:1.00:135.00
2023-03-13 10:11:25,915 : INFO : audreport : AD:3:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296925.xml:1020:2296925:71074269:0000155186:STAUFFER GLOVE SAFETY:2022-10-27:USD:2584.72:12.90:2571.82:47007526:Email:2022-11-01:INVOICE:00001:588534:00002:588534:None:Robin.Nogues@analog.com:None:None:None:None:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296925.pdf:1:47007526:N014187:None:None:157.70:EA:15:2365.50:2:47007526:N014258:None:None:51.58:EA:4:206.32
2023-03-13 10:11:25,930 : INFO : audreport : AD:4:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296961.xml:1010:2296961:0000007624:0000137879:CDW DIRECT LLC:2022-11-01:USD:460.42:35.68:424.74:45922117:Email:2022-11-01:INVOICE:00001:588549:00002:588549:None:cdwbilling@billtrust.com:None:None:None:None:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296961.pdf:1:45922117:997-7413-01:None:None:409.59:EA:1:409.59:2:45922117:SHIPPING:None:None:15.15:EA:1:15.15
2023-03-13 10:11:25,948 : INFO : audreport : AD:5:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296979.xml:1010:2296979:7722074584:0000104006:VANGUARD INTL SEMICONDUCTOR CORP:2022-11-01:USD:22750.00:0.00:22750.00:45971687:Email:2022-11-01:INVOICE:00001:588567:00002:588567:None:VIS_OM@VIS.COM.TW:None:None:None:None:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296979.pdf:1:45971687:8VL8627NQ20XV-B0VG:None:None:910.00:EA:25:22750.00
2023-03-13 10:11:26,176 : INFO : audreport : Processing for client 'AW'
2023-03-13 10:11:26,176 : INFO : audreport : Client:SeqNo:Filename:organization:case_id:invoice_number:supplier_number:supplier_name:posting_date:currency_code:gross_amount:tax_amount:net_amount:order_number:invoice_source:invoice_capture_date:document_type:data_capture_provider_code:data_capture_provider_reference:document_capture_provide_code:document_capture_provider_ref:data_capture_issue:from_email:to_email:box_number:data_captured:data_container:pdf_file_name:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount
2023-03-13 10:11:26,207 : INFO : audreport : AW:3:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296986.xml:1010:2296986:7722074561:0000144983:VANGUARD INTL SEMICONDUCTOR CORP:2022-11-01:USD:22080.00:0.00:22080.00:45968294:Email:2022-11-01:INVOICE:00001:588574:00002:588574:None:VIS_OM@VIS.COM.TW:None:None:None:None:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296986.pdf:1:45968294:8VL8301XV-B0VG:None:None:920.00:EA:24:22080.00
2023-03-13 10:11:26,223 : INFO : audreport : AW:4:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296987.xml:1010:2296987:AN2208001-4:0000147689:VANGUARD INTL SEMICONDUCTOR CORP:2022-11-01:USD:22416.00:0.00:22416.00:45968301:Email:2022-11-01:INVOICE:00001:588575:00002:588575:None:VIS_OM@VIS.COM.TW:None:None:None:None:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296987.pdf:1:45968301:8VL8640-6NQ20XV-B0VG:None:None:934.00:EA:24:22416.00
2023-03-13 10:11:26,238 : INFO : audreport : AW:5:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296988.xml:1020:2296988:7722074555:0000144417:VANGUARD INTL SEMICONDUCTOR CORP:2022-11-01:USD:22416.00:0.00:22416.00:45968265:Email:2022-11-01:INVOICE:00001:588576:00002:588576:None:VIS_OM@VIS.COM.TW:None:None:None:None:ADI_875a41cf-079e-4ca8-a1cc-9d945c711bf0_2296988.pdf:1:45968265:8VL8640NP20XV-B0VG:None:None:934.00:EA:24:22416.00
2023-03-13 10:11:26,363 : INFO : audreport : Processing for client 'CC'
2023-03-13 10:11:26,379 : INFO : audreport : Client:SeqNo:Filename:organization:case_id:invoice_number:supplier_number:supplier_name:posting_date:currency_code:gross_amount:tax_amount:net_amount:order_number:invoice_source:invoice_capture_date:document_type:data_capture_provider_code:data_capture_provider_reference:document_capture_provide_code:document_capture_provider_ref:data_capture_issue:from_email:to_email:box_number:data_captured:data_container:pdf_file_name
2023-03-13 10:11:26,379 : INFO : audreport : CC:1:11a77bd9-ede6-4e53-942e-b9fa103d5736_1361879.xml:00040:1361879:68481161:30150461:CARGILL NV (BEL):2022-11-19:EUR:13350.40:0.00:13350.40:5188633:Email:2022-11-21:INVOICE:None:None:001:1524:None:CargillCSSTEU_Invoice_DoNotReply@cargill.com:None:None:None:None:11a77bd9-ede6-4e53-942e-b9fa103d5736_1361879.pdf
2023-03-13 10:11:26,410 : INFO : audreport : CC:3:2b21abc3-2c56-46df-8e86-f6af8b17560e_1361468.xml:00040:1361468:413502322:30110395:KERRY INGREDIENTS & FLAVOURS LTD:2022-11-18:EUR:20250.00:0.00:20250.00:5191015:Email:2022-11-21:INVOICE:None:None:001:1512:Incorrect PO:noreply.kerryconnect@kerry.com:None:None:None:None:2b21abc3-2c56-46df-8e86-f6af8b17560e_1361468.pdf
2023-03-13 10:11:26,426 : INFO : audreport : CC:5:2b21abc3-2c56-46df-8e86-f6af8b17560e_1361701.xml:00040:1361701:005652 001:30112974:Funkin Cocktails:2022-11-18:EUR:42886.80:0.00:42886.80:5194926:Email:2022-11-21:INVOICE:None:None:001:1518:Incorrect PO:finance@funkin.co.uk:None:None:None:None:2b21abc3-2c56-46df-8e86-f6af8b17560e_1361701.pdf
```

in my expected result you can see each client have single header which has the maximum length of within each client files. How can i do it?

NB: the header in the log means:-

```
2023-03-13 10:11:25,879 : INFO : audreport : Client:SeqNo:Filename:organization:case_id:invoice_number:supplier_number:supplier_name:posting_date:currency_code:gross_amount:tax_amount:net_amount:order_number:invoice_source:invoice_capture_date:document_type:data_capture_provider_code:data_capture_provider_reference:document_capture_provide_code:document_capture_provider_ref:data_capture_issue:from_email:to_email:box_number:data_captured:data_container:pdf_file_name:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount:row_number:order_number:product_code:contract_number:bill_of_lading:unit_price:unit:quantity:amount
```

Comment: Share a valid XML and explain what is the output that should be generated from this xml.

Comment: i have added xml file. i have given the output now and expected output in the question. what i want is to take the `headstr` which is the longest one in each client and it should come first in each client. i have given it in my expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
logger.info("Audit Report capture process start")
for clientid in clients:

    files = xmlgenops.loadFileslist(clientid, os.path.join(filepath, clientid , 'Outgoing'), 'xml')

    totalFiles[clientid] = len(files)
    total_files += len(files)
    logger.info ("Processing for client '{}'".format(clientid))
    files_with_issues = 0
    length_header = 0
    max_length_header = {}
    all_data = []

    for filename in files:
        filename = filename[1]
        fullfilename = os.path.join(filepath, clientid , "Outgoing", filename)
        clientcount[clientid] = clientcount[clientid] + 1 if  clientcount.get(clientid) else 1
        headstr = "Client:SeqNo:Filename"
        datastr = "{}:{}:{}".format(clientid, clientcount[clientid], filename)
        try:
            xmltree = ET.parse(fullfilename)
        except ET.ParseError as err:
            print("xml parse error")
            clienterror[clientid] = clienterror[clientid] + 1 if  clienterror.get(clientid) else 1
            fileswitherror.append("{}:{}".format(datastr, err))
            continue

        myroot = xmltree.getroot()

        for i in myroot.iter('record'):
            for j in i.iter(): 
                if(j.tag not in ignoretags):
                        headstr = "{}:{}".format(headstr,j.tag)
                        datastr = "{}:{}".format(datastr,j.text)
                        
        if len(headstr) > length_header:
            length_header = len(headstr)
            longest_header = headstr

        all_data.append(datastr)

    logger.info("{}:{}".format(clientid, longest_header))
    for i in all_data:
        logger.info(i)

logger.info("Audit Report capture process end")
```

I gave new variables `length_header`, `max_length_header` and `all_data`. i checked header of each file and compred every time it goes through the next file and stored the longest header in one variable if it is longer than the previous header.

Comment: Is there really a need to iter 'Record' twice?

Comment: Yes, you need to iter twice because if you want to take a tag inside a tag we need to iter twice